# Regex with fixed begin and end

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following stuff - and I'm trying get property `calc(100% - 14px)` with no luck:

```
var a = 'width:calc(100% - 14px); adsasd';
var b = 'width:calc(100% - 14px]; adsasd';

console.log(a.match('width:calc\(.*?\)$'));
console.log(b.match('width:calc\(.*?\)$'));
```

**Example** http://jsfiddle.net/zFacF/

Both console.log will output the same result

```
["width:calc(100% - 14px); adsasd", 
 "(100% - 14px); adsasd"] 

["width:calc(100% - 14px]; adsasd", 
 "(100% - 14px]; adsasd"]
```

How can I get `calc(100% - 14px)` from given string?

**@Solved** with

`/width:\s?(calc\(.*\))/`

Because with inline `style="width: calc(100% - 14px)"` without `;` and with spaces beteween `width` and `calc` not matches.

http://jsfiddle.net/zFacF/5/

Comment: it's css3 function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc

Comment: What's with the square bracket at the end oth the second calc?

Comment: @AllysondePaula please consider accepting the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/width:(calc\(.*\))/`

if you want to account for square brackets:

`/width:(calc[(\[].*[)\]])/`

Answer (score 1):

The `$` at the end of your regex is streching your pattern match till end..`$` depicts the end of string..

Use `width:(calc\(.*?\));`

`Group 1` contains your required data

Comment: Thanks in given example work. But without separeted commas `;` in case of inline `style="with:calc(100% - 14px)"` will not matches

Comment: @AllysondePaula try `width:(calc\(.*?\))(\s|;)`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work alright: http://jsfiddle.net/zFacF/1/

The $ was making the .* match all the way to the end. Instead I added a `;` to stop that from happening.

Comment: Will work on given example, but no works with inline `style="width: calc(100% - 14px)"` without `;` - than a friend helps me to find `/width:\s?(calc\(.*\))/`

Answer (score 1):

If you want also to validate that string has same form use:

```
^width:(calc\(.*\));.*$
```

The first group (group[1]) will contain required result.

If you don't need validation use only:

```
calc\(.*\)
```

In this case result is whole match.